# Swift4 Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?)

Tags: json, swift, httprequest

```
func DoLogin(_ email:String, _ password:String)
{
    struct User: Decodable {
        let sfname: String
        let slname: String
        let email: String
        let sid: Int
    }

    let url = URL(string: "http://URL")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password + ""
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print(response!)
        }

       if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
        let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: responseString)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

So the aim is to decode the HTTP response `responseString` in order to save the information into the properties of `User`, but I keep getting the same error popping up after inserting the line of code in order to decode the HTTP response (`myStruct`). I feel it has something to do with Do Try Catch error handling but can't manage to figure it out.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: responseString)
```

The completion handler of

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest, completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)
```

does not allow throwing or re-throwing exceptions. If it had, the signature would be something like this instead:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest, completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) throws -> Void)
```

(note the `throws` in the method signature)

Also, you need to make sure you change `responseString` to `data`. The `decode` method takes a `Data` object, not a `String`. Converting `data` to a `String` is actually not needed at all, so you can remove this `if` statement from your code:

```
if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

Try doing something like this instead:

```
do {
    let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
    //do something with myStruct
} catch let error as NSError {
    //do something with error
}
```

or this:

```
if let myStruct = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data) {
    //do something with myStruct
} else {
    //handle myStruct being nil
}
```